# How to cross verify the resultant E-NFA in "Regular Expression to E-NFA" is correct?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, nondeterminism, theory

Let's say that we want to convert the regular expression: (ab + a)* to Finite Automata, where '+' is union and '*' is kleene star. Using the Thompson method, [Thompson Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction#Rules)

I end up with this:[image]

My question is, is there a way to cross verify that my E-NFA accepts the language of Regular expression mentioned at the start in this post? I tried converting the Resultant E-NFA back to Regular Expression using Arden's Theorem. But I end up with a inifite substitution for the final state q9

Also, is my constructed E-NFA correct?

EDIT: Adding Converting "resultant E-NFA to RE"

epsilon transition = e

q1 = e

q2 = q1e + q8e

q3 = q2e

q4 = q3a

q5 = q4b

q6 = q2e

q7 = q6a

q8 = q7e

q9 = q8e + q1e

Since we have to final states, q1 and q9 we need to substitue other values in q1 and q9. We will start with q9

q9 = q8e + q1e

q9 = q7ee + e

q9 = q6aee + e

q9 = q2eaee + e

q9 = (q1e + q8e)eaee + e

q9 = q1eeaee + q8eeaee + e

q9 = q1a + q8a + e

We again got q8, so this chain will always repeat. So what do i do from here?

Comment: Yes your answer is correct, trying some strings in language ($\varepsilon$,$a$,$ab$,$aa$,$abab$,$aab$,$aba$,...) should give a strong intuition about its correctness, to be certain surely reconverting it back to a Regular expression is good, if you have a problem maybe modify your question to add a picture of your conversion attempt, although trying some inputs on a small NFA like this should probably suffice

Comment: @Moslem I have added the "conversion that i tried" as an EDIT, it would be great if you have a look at it. Also one more question, whether the start state will be accept state <- this can easily be decided by just looking the RE and seeing if the Regular Expression can result into string of length 0 right?

Comment: I think this is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a concrete question. Our questions need to help future works but this question seems a college task to me.

Comment: Oh it isn't a college task, may be the way i wrote the title and content made it seem like that. I just used that Regular Expression as an example, i was more interested in "cross verifying" and to do that the best way is to solving using example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the substitutions in order so that you don't get a loop, here is the solution

$q1 = \varepsilon$

$q_2 = q_1 \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_3 = q_2 \varepsilon$

$q_4 = q_3a$

$q_5 = q_4b$

$q_6 = q_2 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = q5 \varepsilon + q_6 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + q1 \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_1 = \varepsilon$ in every other rule

$q_2 = \varepsilon \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_3 = q_2 \varepsilon$

$q_4 = q_3a$

$q_5 = q_4b$

$q_6 = q_2 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = q5 \varepsilon + q_6 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon \varepsilon = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon $

---

Substitute for $q_2 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$ in every other rule

$q_3 = (\varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon) \varepsilon = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_4 = q_3a$

$q_5 = q_4b$

$q_6 = (\varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon) \varepsilon = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = q5 \varepsilon + q_6 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_3 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$ in every other rule

$q_4 = (\varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon)a = a + q_8a$

$q_5 = q_4b$

$q_6 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = q5 \varepsilon + q_6 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_4 = a + q_8a$ in every other rule

$q_5 = (a + q_8a)b = ab + q_8ab$

$q_6 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = q5 \varepsilon + q_6 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_5 = ab + q_8ab$ in every other rule

$q_6 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$

$q_7 = q_6a$

$q_8 = (ab + q_8ab) \varepsilon + q_7 \varepsilon = ab + q_8ab + q_7 \varepsilon$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_6 = \varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon$ in every other rule

$q_7 = (\varepsilon  + q_8 \varepsilon)a = a + q_8 a$

$q_8 = ab + q_8ab + q_7 \varepsilon $

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_7 = a + q_8 a$ in every other rule

$q_8 = ab + q_8ab + (a + q_8 a) \varepsilon = ab + q_8 ab + a + q_8 a = a + ab + q_8(a+ab)$

Now we can apply Arden's Theroem

$q_8 = a + ab + (a+ab)^* = (a+ab)^*$

$q_9 = q_8 \varepsilon + \varepsilon$

---

Substitute for $q_8 = a + (ab)^*$

$q_9 = (a+ab)^* \varepsilon + \varepsilon = (a+ab)^*$

And here is our solution :)

Comment: Ah, i should have worked at it more. Thank You for typing all of that out, this is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Glad to help :)